# Ado.Net Entity produces "namespace cannot be found"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've seen several possible solutions to this, but none have worked for me.

After adding a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my .Net Forms C# web project, I am unable to use it.

Perhaps I made a mistake adding it?  The name of the file added is QcFormData.edmx.

I'm instantiating this incorrectly? I tried adding the line:

```
QcFormData db = new QcFormData();


Error   13  The type or namespace name 'QcFormData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've followed the suggestions that I found online that did not help:

1) made sure there is "using System.Data.Entity"

2) made sure the dll exists.

3) made sure the reference exists.

4) one post said use using System.**Web**.Data.Entity; but I do not see that available.

What am I missing?

**QcFormData.edmx**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="MyCoModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="MyCoModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="QcFieldValues" EntityType="MyCoModel.Store.QcFieldValues" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="QcFieldValues">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="FieldID" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="DateTimeAdded" Type="datetime" />
          <Property Name="OrderReserveNumber" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="MyCoModel" Alias="Self" p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="MyCoEntities" p1:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="QcFieldValues" EntityType="MyCoModel.QcFieldValue" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="QcFieldValue">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" p1:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="FieldID" Type="String" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="DateTimeAdded" Type="DateTime" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="OrderReserveNumber" Type="String" MaxLength="50" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="MyCoModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="MyCoEntities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="QcFieldValues">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MyCoModel.QcFieldValue">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="QcFieldValues">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FieldID" ColumnName="FieldID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FieldValue" ColumnName="FieldValue" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="DateTimeAdded" ColumnName="DateTimeAdded" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="OrderReserveNumber" ColumnName="OrderReserveNumber" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="True" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="True" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: how is QcFormDataContainer defined?

Comment: No, it's in the root of the project, along with the aspx file and aspx.cs file I'm calling it from.

Comment: Now, QcFormDataContainer no longer appears in Intellisense after cleaning and recompiling.  But I still cannot access the QcFormData object.

Comment: is it possible to post code for QcFormDataContainer ?

Comment: What namespace is it in?

Comment: you don't even bother posting required code.and expecting to get to result! it is just copying and pasting some code!!!

Comment: Ok, you gave me 6 minutes.  I was getting the code together.  I posted QcFormData.edmx if that helps.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the "using" for the namespace that QcFormDataContainer exists in?

Comment: No, I think it might be a namespace issue.  I've had other namespace issues with this project. Trying to figure out now exactly what namespace I'm supposed to add.

Comment: @Dave - there are three of us telling you that. If you did not add the correct "using/Imports" to the top of the code file, you will not be able to resolve the references correctly.

Comment: Please post the code for QcFormDataContainer, including the namespace declaration.

Comment: The EDMX is not very useful for this problem.

Comment: I do not have a file called QcFormDataContainer so I do not know how to post code for that.  I have files called QcFormData.edmx and other files that begin with QcFormData.*.

Answer (score 0):

I added Linq to SQL Classes item, instead of the ADO.Net Entity Data Model item, and it now works fine without need to add a namespace to the top of my code.  If someone has any suggestions on a specific solution better than this, that would be great.  I'm happy to post whichever specific file asked for.

As I mentioned above, if it is a namespace issue, I still do not know how to resolve it.  People suggested I failed to do something, but not exactly what, namespace to add, where to find it, etc.